# Display current date at the top of the table

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to display the current date (at this example 2017-11-16) at top of the data frame. when i download data, the new date appear at the bottom of data frame.
how can i change it?

```
                 Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    
Date                                                                            
2017-11-13  173.500000  174.500000  173.399994  173.970001  173.970001  
2017-11-14  173.039993  173.479996  171.179993  171.339996  171.339996  
2017-11-15  169.970001  170.320007  168.380005  169.080002  169.080002  
2017-11-16  171.179993  171.869995  170.300003  171.100006  171.100006
```

My code is:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import pandas as pd

DayToPast=5
today = datetime.date.today()
end = datetime.date.today()
start = today-datetime.timedelta(days=DayToPast)

df=web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)

print(df)
```

Thanks & Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "today" is the maximal date in your dataframe's index, you can just sort your data by descending order of its index:

```
df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```